# How to print a diagonal matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How to print a diagonal matrix in python?

```
def crie_matriz(n_linhas = 5, n_colunas = 5):
    matriz = []
    for i in range(n_linhas):
        linha = []
        for j in range(n_colunas):
            linha.append(i + 1)
        matriz.append(linha)
        print(matriz[i][0],matriz[i][1], matriz[i][2],matriz[i][3], matriz[i][4])
    return matriz

A = crie_matriz()
```

I must follow some rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite close, just modifying couple of lines:

```
def crie_matriz(n_linhas = 5, n_colunas = 5):
    matriz = []
    for i in range(n_linhas):
        linha = []
        for j in range(n_colunas):
            linha.append(0)        # <<< 
        linha[i] = i + 1           # <<<
        matriz.append(linha)
        print(matriz[i][0],matriz[i][1], matriz[i][2],matriz[i][3], matriz[i][4])
    return matriz

A = crie_matriz()
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 5
```

Comment: what happened to few lines as possible and not printing the 0s lol?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with numpy:

```
import np
matriz = np.zeros((5,5))
np.fill_diagonal(matriz,[1,2,3,4,5])
```

output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 5.]])
```

to make it look like your original output:

```
import sys
np.savetxt(sys.stdout,matriz,fmt="%.f")
```

output:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 5
```

to not print the blanks, you could do something like:

```
for i,val in enumerate(np.diagonal(matriz)):
    print(i*'  ','%.f' %val)
```

output:

```
 1
   2
     3
       4
         5
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to eliminate the zeros ... Print with blanks instead of zero ... Without the zeros ... do I need to do a function?

Comment: I put the rules in the question